# QT6: Не отображаются картинки большого размера

Tags: c++, qt, qtquick, qt6

Сгенерировал картинку `2000x61517` и попытался отобразить её через `Image`, но картинка не отобразилась.
Подбором выяснил что нормально отображаются картинки следующих размеров `1000x33554`, `2000x16777`.
У меня почти нет опыта работы с Qt и возможно это тривиальная задача, но я не смог найти способа её решения.

Comment: [В реализации растрового отрисовщика использется `short`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qpainter.html#limitations) => максимальный размер 32767x32767

Comment: При этом изображение размером 1000x33554 судя по описанию может быть отображено, а может быть и нет. Или с ним может произойти что-нибудь в процессе отображения. В любом случае для отображения больших растровых данных стоит использовать обзорники или тайлы.